# SUM of multiple VLOOKUP

Tags: excel, excel-formula, key, vlookup

It seems like a simple problem, but I do not manage to solve it. I have the following tables:

#### Values

```
| Key | Value |
|-----|-------|
|  A  |   1   |
|  B  |   2   |
|  C  |   3   |
```

#### Results

```
| Foo | Bar |
|-----|-----|
|  A  |  B  |
|  C  |  B  |
|  A  |  A  |
|  B  |  C  |
| ... | ... |
```

What I am looking for is a final row in the `Results` table that looks for the `key` in the `Values` table, takes its `value` and sums all the `keys` in a column (i.e. `FOO` and `BAR`). The final result would be:

```
| Foo | Bar |
|-----|-----|
|  A  |  B  |
|  C  |  B  |
|  A  |  A  |
|  B  |  C  |
|-----|-----|
|  7  |  8  |
```

I have been trying with different VLOOKUP, INDEX and MATCH functions, but still I am not able. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asume you want a solution **without** extra columns. Then you are into Array formulas (a.k.a CSE or ControlShiftEnter functions).

Combination of `{=SUM(VLOOKUP(...))}` doesn't work, but combination of `{=SUM(SUMIF(...))}` does:

in A12 enter `=SUM(SUMIF($A$1:$A$3;A7:A10;$B$1:$B$3))` and save with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. You then can copy this to B12.

[image]

Problem is you will need to change the Array function every time you add values to the list A7:B10 (or you initially make the range sufficiently large) ... this would speak more for extra =VLOOKUP() columns as suggested by CustomX.

Comment: In principle, my `key-value` table will not change, so this is perfect for my problem. Thanks!

Comment: If you want to avoid CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER you can replace SUM with `SUMPRODUCT` and then you don't need "array entry"

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure of other solutions, but you could solve this by using an extra 2 columns, `E` and `F` for example.

Enter this in column E: `=VLOOKUP(C2;$A$1:$B$3;2;0)`

Enter this in column F: `=VLOOKUP(D2;$A$1:$B$3;2;0)`

Pull the formulas down and add a `SUM` at the bottom of column `C` and `D` to calculate columns `E` and `F`.

**Extra:** These are the columns I used for your examples.

- Key = column A
- Value = column B
- Foo = column C
- Bar = column D

Comment: Nice! That is a way and it solves my problem :) But I still wonder if there is a more "straightforward" way. Thanks!